# Xcode Cloud Workflow, initial creation, cannot change Primary Repository

Tags: xcode-cloud

Trying to to create a workflow for Xcode Cloud in Xcode.  The issue I am having is that I am unable to complete the workflow creation, which i believe to be due to the following issue:

The primary repository path is going to some derived data path that is for a third party repository that we have integrated via SPM

[image: default selection for primary repository in workflow creation]

when in the drop down selection, it is only showing SPM connected repositories.
[image: Dropdown selection for Primary Repository]

Then in the final stage, I cant proceed to connect github, etc
[image: final stage of workflow creation]

if anyone has any ideas on how to proceed from here, that would be appreciated :) It's especially confusing because I am able to pull up the correct branches when editing triggers

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me when I tried to create workflow, but didn't set up the origin branch in my repo, so i only had the git initialized, but not remote branch. After I created the repo in GitHub and pushed changes to remote, my workflow started to show the Primary Repository as intended

Comment: this was an old project that i was setting up for xcode cloud